# select call returning before timeout on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm starting to hate sockets, please help.

So I'm trying to connect to a location in the localhost network. This might or might not be online. Since I want to wait a timeout shorter than default, I'm using non-blocking `connect`, + `select`.

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001);
address.sin_port = htons(port);

const int timeout_int = 100; //in milliseconds
struct timeval timeout = { 0, timeout_int * 1000 };

SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

#ifdef WIN32
u_long iMode = 1;
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &iMode);
#else
int socketFlags = fcntl( s, F_GETFL, 0 )
socketFlags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl( s, F_SETFL, socketFlags )
#endif

connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) clientService, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

fd_set sock;
FD_ZERO(&sock);
FD_SET(s, &sock);

int result = select(s + 1, NULL, &sock, NULL, &timeout);
```

Of course there is a lot more error checking that I've left out; but don't worry, I'm doing it, and everything appears to be in perfect health except that it's dead, so to speak.

On Windows it works: it waits the timeout and if there is nothing to be found, it returns 0 into `result`, which precisely means "timeout".

Linux, however, in the exact same condition, almost immediately returns 1 -which would mean that the socket is ready for writing! Indeed, the socket flag is still set.

Now, it has been suggested that I do this

```
int soError;
socklen_t len = sizeof(soError);
getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&soError, &len);
```

Then only if `soError` is `0`, the connection succeeded.

But why is the timeout not waited? Can i trust Linux to know that if I get to that point, there is already no hope of receiving an answer? 
I have tried sleeping for the rest of the timeout and then checking again; but in that case I get `soError == 0` in all cases, so it doesn't work.

Or am I doing something completely wrong at some other point?

Comment: What is `clientService` ? BTW 100 uSec is pretty short. Why not make it 5 sec or so?

Comment: Since `select()` is just checking to see if writing to the socket will block or not, what happens if you try writing to the socket?

Comment: @ChrisTurner non-blocking connects are explicitly specified to be selectable for writing and should return when the connect succeeded.

Comment: I cannot confirm this behavior. Trying to connect to a non-responsive host/port, I get `EINPROGRESS` from `select()`, as expected. If the connect is successful, I get `1` unless I reduce the timeout to a very low value (e.g 10us)

Comment: The question seems to be confusing. Are you trying to read or to write to your socket? If you try to read you shall use the following sequence: call connect, if it returns -1 and errno == EINPROGRESS, then call select as you did (checking socket for write), when select returns 1 check SO_ERROR for possible error. If there is no error, you are connected. Now you can read or write to the socket. If you want to wait for an input, use another select (now checking the socket for read). If it returns 1 a message is received and can be read. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Marian I am trying to detect whether the server is listening or not on the given port. The caller will then do what it has to do with the information, it's not under my control.

Comment: @joop because the server will always be on the local network (most likely localhost itself, or a VM), so it should be fast. And I need it to be fast; don't get me started on it, but it's called multiple times where performance matters -not down to microseconds thankfully, but a second is a long time.

Comment: @dhke you get `errno == EINPROGRESS`, but not from `select`; that's what `connect` set it when it started a nonblocking connection! If before calling `select` you set `errno` to `EGRANDMOTHERINAWHEELBARROW` (which you'll have suitably `#defined` to any random number), then that's the value you'll be finding after. As you should, because `errno` is only meaningful in case the return code was `SOCKET_ERROR`, and this isn't the case!

Comment: If `select` returns that the socket is writable, then you are connected and the server is listening. You can  `write` to the socket. In your case `select` returned before timeout, because the connection was established faster than the timeout 100ms. What is the problem? Have you tried to simply write something to the socket? And what exactly did not work?

Comment: @Marian if I try to write to a port which should be closed, I get an error (unsurprisingly). Yet `select` returns before the timeout which a success return code. I can just try to write, but I should be able to tell without a second network round trip.

Comment: In linux, there is no `SOCKET_ERROR`. So you'll need to carefully port from Windows to Linux. Start by checking the return value for **every** syscall and inspect errno if -1. Also `#elif` is not valid preprocessor sysntax. Please post real and complete code.

Comment: @joop Sorry, we have a compatibility library for platform-specific code. `SOCKET_ERROR` is `-1` on Linux. I'm checking against it every single system call, and I'm checking the error code (`errno` on Linux) every time the return code indicates an error.

Comment: What you have is a `non blocking connect`, and the behaviour is perfectly normal. GIYF BTW: if select says that the fd is writeble: it means you can write to it without blocking. The write could return 0 or -1, but it won't block.

Comment: @joop ok, now this makes me understand a bit more. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not all connect errors require a timeout. ECONNREFUSED for example causes an immediate failure. The timeout is here for the case where the peer doesn't respond at all.

Comment: You mean that `select` receives some thing called `ECONNREFUSED`? Because what _it_ returns to _me_ looks for all intents and purposes like a success; unless I check `getsockopt` at least.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the connection return code and only if it returns ERROR and errno is EWOULDBLOCK or EINPROGRESS (depends on OS), call select. It may be that the connection is established on the connection call, and therefore a call to select returns that you could already write to that socket